# row values are getting repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have list of value shown in table where each row have checkbox type and the list looks like this

[image]

when i click the last one that row value is getting but if i click the second row two times that rows values is coming out and if i go for third,three times of that row value is coming

here is my code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var qua=[];
   var amnt=[];
   $("#getdata").on('click',function () {
   var form_data={      
                    agent_name: $('#agent_name').val(),
                    number: $('#number').val(),
                    number_from: $('#number_from').val(),
                    number_to: $('#number_to').val(),
                    quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
                    amount: $('#amount').val(),
                    date: $('#date').val(),
                    commision: $('#commision').val(),
                    profit: $('#profit').val(),
                    agent_amount: $('#agent_amount').val(),
                    user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
                    type: $("#abc_type_"+$("input[name=select_type]:checked").val()).val()
                  }
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control/ajax_data',
    data: form_data,
    dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
    success: function(data){ 
      var fragment = '';


   for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){
     fragment += '<tr class="item-row"><td><input type="hidden" id="add_type" name="add_type[]" value="'+ data.json[i].type +'">'+ data.json[i].type +'</td><td><input type="hidden" id="add_number" name="add_number[]" value="'+ data.json[i].number +'">'+ data.json[i].number +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_quantity" id="add_quantity" name="add_quantity[]" value="'+ data.json[i].quantity +'">'+ data.json[i].quantity +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_amount" id="add_amount" name="add_amount[]" value="'+ data.json[i].amount +'">'+ data.json[i].amount +'</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="add_checkbox" name="add_checkbox" id="add_checkbox'+i+'" value="1" checked></td></tr>'; 
    }

   qua_sum = 0;num_sum = 0;txt='';
   $("#table").append(fragment);

   $(".add_checkbox").on('click',function(){
      alert();


     if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        qua_su=$("#total_quantity").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_quantity").text());
        num_su=$("#total_amount").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_amount").text());
        var q=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_quantity').val();
        alert(q);
        var a=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_amount').val();
        alert(a);
        qu=$('#total_quantity').text(parseInt(qua_su) + parseInt(q));
        nu=$('#total_amount').text(parseInt(num_su) + parseInt(a));
    }
    else
    {

      qua_su=$("#total_quantity").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_quantity").text());
      num_su=$("#total_amount").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_amount").text());
      var q=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_quantity').val();
      alert(q);
      var a=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_amount').val();
      alert(a);
      qu=$('#total_quantity').text(qua_su-q);
      nu=$('#total_amount').text(num_su-a);
    }


 // Then you write the output where you want :

    }); 

  },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }

});
});

 return false;  

 });
```

hope you understood the problem clearly.

My data looks like this

```
{"json":[{"agent_name":"admin","number":"212","type":"super","quantity":"33","amount":"330.00","date":"2018-02-21 15:58:57","commision":"10.00","profit":"330.00","agent_amount":"0.00","user_id":"1"}]}
{"json":[{"agent_name":"admin","number":"444","type":"super","quantity":"44","amount":"440.00","date":"2018-02-21 15:58:57","commision":"10.00","profit":"440.00","agent_amount":"0.00","user_id":"1"}]}
{"json":[{"agent_name":"admin","number":"444","type":"super","quantity":"44","amount":"440.00","date":"2018-02-21 15:58:57","commision":"10.00","profit":"440.00","agent_amount":"0.00","user_id":"1"}]}
```

Comment: We need to also see the HTML in order to recreate the problem. That said, it sounds like you're duplicating event handlers, somehow.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the HTML code is placed inside the for loop

Comment: Just, what do you want as output exactly? I thought it was an id problem so on click you get wrong value but you want to get the total of column checked, right? Or Idon't get it, so can you explain what you want please?

Comment: @MickaelLeger yes if i click a particular row i want that particular row value to be added.i had a total amount in one id and while uncheck the checkbox of a row i want that value of the row to be reduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var data = {
      json: [
          {type: 'super', number: '100', quantity: 10, amount: 100.00},
          {type: 'super', number: '200', quantity: 20, amount: 200.00},
          {type: 'super', number: '300', quantity: 30, amount: 300.00}
      ]
  };
  
  var fragment = '';
  for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){
      fragment += '<tr class="item-row"><td><input type="hidden" id="add_type" name="add_type[]" value="'+ data.json[i].type +'">'+ data.json[i].type +'</td><td><input type="hidden" id="add_number" name="add_number[]" value="'+ data.json[i].number +'">'+ data.json[i].number +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_quantity" id="add_quantity" name="add_quantity[]" value="'+ data.json[i].quantity +'">'+ data.json[i].quantity +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_amount" id="add_amount" name="add_amount[]" value="'+ data.json[i].amount +'">'+ data.json[i].amount +'</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="add_checkbox" name="add_checkbox" id="add_checkbox'+i+'" value="1" checked></td></tr>'; 
  }

  $('#table').html(fragment);
  
  $(".add_checkbox").on('click',function(){
     var checkbox_list = $(".add_checkbox"); // select all your checkbox elt

     // You put your sum to 0 (or if you have an other value from an other place than your table, init them with this value
     var qua_su = 0;
     var num_su = 0;

     // You loop through all you checkbox to see if they are check or not
     $.each(checkbox_list, function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             qua_su += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.add_quantity').val()) ;
             num_su += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.add_amount').val()) ;
         }
     }); 

     // Then you write the output where you want :
     $('#total_quantity').html(qua_su);   
     $('#total_amount').html(num_su);
     
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
</table>

<p>Total Quantity: <span id="total_quantity">60</span></p>
<p>Total Amount: <span id="total_amount">600</span></p>
```

First, you loop and create row with same id so after each id, add the i value to have unique id :

```
// every time you have an id, do :
... + id="yourIDname_" + i + ...
```

EG :

```
for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){
    fragment += '... id="add_type_"' + i + '....
}
```

This way you will have unique id for each row.

Then try this way maybe :

```
// Trigger every time a checkbox is click
$(".add_checkbox").on('click',function(){
     var checkbox_list = $(".add_checkbox"); // select all your checkbox elt

     // You put your sum to 0 (or if you have an other value from an other place than your table, init them with this value
     var qua_su = 0;
     var num_su = 0;

     // You loop through all you checkbox to see if they are check or not
     $.each(checkbox_list, function() {
         if ($(this).is('checked') {
             // you get the value of your row and added it to your sum
             qua_su += // the value
             num_su += // the value
         }
     } 

     // Then you write the output where you want :
     $('#total_quantity').html(qua_su);   
     $('#total_amount').html(num_su);
});
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: brother for getting unique i chooses the class name

Comment: Yeah I saw after, having unique id is still better but not the anwser. Can you explain the output of what you want (I comment your question) so I can edit my anwser please?

Comment: see @Rafael Paulino answer that the concept needed

Comment: @user_777 Ok so my approach : every time someone click on a checkbox, you init your sum at 0, you check all your checkbox if they are checked, if yes : you get the value of the row  (with the id for example it could be easier) and added this value to your sum var, then you write the final output. Is it clear and do you think it could works? I didn't write all the code but the main logic is here

Comment: thank you brother you saved my time a lot..thank you

Comment: Glad if I helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I get your code running. It seems to be OK. Is that the behavior you want?

```js
$(function() {
  var data = {
      json: [
          {type: 'super', number: '100', quantity: 10, amount: 100.00},
          {type: 'super', number: '200', quantity: 20, amount: 200.00},
          {type: 'super', number: '300', quantity: 30, amount: 300.00}
      ]
  };
  
  var fragment = '';
  for(var i=0; i < data.json.length; i++){
      fragment += '<tr class="item-row"><td><input type="hidden" id="add_type" name="add_type[]" value="'+ data.json[i].type +'">'+ data.json[i].type +'</td><td><input type="hidden" id="add_number" name="add_number[]" value="'+ data.json[i].number +'">'+ data.json[i].number +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_quantity" id="add_quantity" name="add_quantity[]" value="'+ data.json[i].quantity +'">'+ data.json[i].quantity +'</td><td><input type="hidden" class="add_amount" id="add_amount" name="add_amount[]" value="'+ data.json[i].amount +'">'+ data.json[i].amount +'</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="add_checkbox" name="add_checkbox" id="add_checkbox'+i+'" value="1" checked></td></tr>'; 
  }

  $('#table').html(fragment);

  $(".add_checkbox").on('click',function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
          qua_su=$("#total_quantity").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_quantity").text());
          num_su=$("#total_amount").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_amount").text());
          var q=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_quantity').val();
          var a=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_amount').val();
          $('#total_quantity').text(parseInt(qua_su) + parseInt(q));
          $('#total_amount').text(parseInt(num_su) + parseInt(a));
      }
      else
      { 
          qua_su=$("#total_quantity").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_quantity").text());
          num_su=$("#total_amount").text() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#total_amount").text());
          var q=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_quantity').val();
          var a=$(this).closest('.item-row').find('.add_amount').val();
          $('#total_quantity').text(qua_su-q);
          $('#total_amount').text(num_su-a);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
</table>

<p>Total Quantity: <span id="total_quantity">60</span></p>
<p>Total Amount: <span id="total_amount">600</span></p>
```

Comment: yaa this is what i want but for me the second row performs two times and first row performs three times

Comment: i updating my question with data please have a look

Comment: Your data seems strange to me. You have three lines (each one is a valid JSON object). Inside you have the "json" that is an array. Each array (in each line) contains only ONE item. How are you getting this data from the backend? I have a hunch that your problem might be in the function that created the table (and how many times it gets executed). Please provide more code and I shall help you for sure.

Comment: Everytime you "get data", you really want to append to the existing table? Or you want to replace all data on table with the new values?